# PUT request on Magento 2 REST API through Postman

Tags: magento2, rest-api, webapi

I'm trying a **PUT** on Magento 2 REST API through Postman like this:

```
https://domain/rest/V1/products/IP_X
```

With only a price change on the JSON content.

I'm getting the following error message:

```
{
    "message": "\"%fieldName\" is required. Enter and try again.",
    "parameters": {
        "fieldName": "product"
    }
}
```

The REST API [spec](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/rest/list.html) indicates the URL to be `PUT /V1/products/:sku` and the JSON should include only the parameter to change.

Any idea?

Comment: I found the answer, the json content should be like this:

{
  "product": {
    "price": "500.55"
  }
}

Comment: @GeneralGrievance I added the community wiki answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

your data is in json format. Removed json_encode from there it will resolve this issue.

Comment: Hi Anas, the "Content-Type" needs to be "application/json", the problem was that I was doing a bad content package. Here it is how it worked:

{ "product": { "price": "500.55" } }

Tx for your help!

Answer (score 0):

From A Zuniga's comment, the json content should be like this:

```
{ "product": { "price": "500.55" } }
```